# Rigging: How to rig an emotionless dog face and ears?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, rigify

Im continuing on my journey on making more models in blender. I made a funky looking doggo. I am well aware he has alot of bones for his tentacles. Im just trying to get help with his face. I am finding I am having a hard time making his top and bottom jaw open correctly. It should open like a hinge. very mechanical. But when I open the jaw, It sort of.... bends. same with the ears

I used the Wolf rigify and modified it slight modifications to it and parented it with automatic weights

So. in short. How do I make it where the ears and jaws move as if they are on  hinges?

File here: https://pasteall.org/blend/5af82a1403ec424c9099313ec84bec42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing your armature is stretched so you need to apply the scale. For the lower mouth, at least 4 bones influence its topology, you need to correct that in *Weight Paint* mode:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So I deleted the random bones in the side and i went into weight painting mode but I can't seem to get it to work. How does the program know the place i am painting belongs to that bone?

Comment: You need to select the armature in Object mode, shift select the dog, switch it to Weight Paint mode, select the bone you want with Ctrl left click, and paint. If you want to paint through, deactivate the Brush Settings > Advanced > Front Faces Only option in the N panel, and also select Falloff > Projected

Comment: To be honest.. I think this worked. but im not really good at it.. sorry Moon.